# VB.NET (WebRequest Authentication Issue)

Tags: vb.net, authentication, web, webrequest

I'm new to WebRequest authentication and have been researching how to authenticate w/ a couple websites to pull some excel data from them. Couple things I'm confused about is

a.) how to properly read a log from Fiddler (using this to pick up get/post data from the website authentication)

b.) how do use the data from Fiddler to program the VB.NET WebRequest properly.

I've been able to authenticate w/ websites that use simple authentication HTTPS, but any site that does any redirects/REST/cookie auth I'm lost...

Let me know if I can provide anymore detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim req As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(Url)
        If Not Login = Nothing AndAlso Not Password = Nothing Then
            Dim myCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache()
            myCache.Add(New Uri(Url), "Basic", New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Login, Password))
            req.Credentials = myCache
        End If
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim ss as string = sr.ReadToEnd
        'Save it as excel & close stream
        sr.Close()
```